# how trigger when data provider of the flex chart changes?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

Is it possible to trigger when data provider of the flex chart changes ? Any ideas guys ?
i used oncreation complete but it is not working when change data source of the chart dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **Changewatcher** class.

```
import mx.binding.utils.ChangeWatcher;
import mx.events.PropertyChangeEvent;

ChangeWatcher.watch(this, "dataProvider", watchHandler);

private function watchHandler(e:PropertyChangeEvent):void
 {
                    // Do Something
 }
```

Otherwise try this,
Add collection change listener to chart itself like below.

```
chart.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, onChartDataProviderChange);

private function onChartDataProviderChange(e:CollectionEvent):void
     {
                        // Do Something
     }

if(condition1){
chart.dataprovider=provider1;
} 
if(condition2){
chart.dataprovider=provider2;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply.this works only when change whole data provider. im tying to trigger when same dataProvider changes.

Comment: what you mean by whole dataprovider? you need to replace "dataprovider" with your dataprovider name in the code above. Else post the your code corresponding to the portion in question to give you exact solution.

Comment: if(condition1){chart.dataprovider=provider1}
if(condition2){chart.dataprovider=provider2} this is exactly what im expecting.length of the provider one and provider2 not same.

Comment: Edited my post check it.

Answer (score 1):

If the `dataProvider` is an `ArrayCollection` you can add a listener to the dataProvider object collection itself:

```
dataProvider.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE,listernerFunction);
```

Notice that if you replace the entire `dataProvider` object for example with the code

```
dataProvider  = null;
dataProvider = new ArrayCollection();
```

You will not trigger the event and you have to add a new listener to the new object.

Otherwise you can add listener to the chart itself that will be trigger every time the data provider object is replaced but it will not be trigger when the the collection itself changes.

```
chart.addEventListener(PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE,funct);
[..]
protected function funct( event:PropertyChangeEvent):void{
    if(event.property=="dataProvider"){
        //Your code
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.But i need to trigger when the collection itself changes.